# Was X-Force just a marketing McGuffin?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool, deadpool-2

The marketing team went out of their way to include the idea that they were a big part of the movie, but they ended being on screen for like 2 minutes. The way they were dispatched was hilarious, but after thinking about it afterwards, I felt more and more like they were basically just a marketing ploy to sell more tickets. In my opinion, they served absolutely no purpose in the movie, and they could have been completely removed and the plot would have advanced just the same.

Comment: “the marketing team went out of their way to include the idea that they were a big part of the movie” — did they? I think telling people stuff that might get them to go see the movie is the marketing team’s entire job.

Comment: “The way they were dispatched was hilarious, and I was busting out laughing (as was everyone in the theater)... In my opinion, they served absolutely no purpose in the movie”. So they made you, and everyone else in the theater, bust out laughing, during a movie that’s meant to be funny. But they served absolutely no purpose in the movie. You’re right! It’s a ploy! An evil, evil ploy to make you laugh in exchange for the price of a movie ticket!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to the director and the writers, it was a prank:

> [Director] David Leitch says the basic concept of killing off these characters right away was to “fuck with the audience through Deadpool’s lens”, and co-writer Rhett Reese adds that they actually shot additional scenes with the X-Force team for trailers, just to throw off the audience:
>
> > “One of the things we did, we asked the actors if they’d be willing to shoot extra footage – that indicated they were in more of the movie than we were actually going to use them in. So, Terry Crews and Bill Skarsgård and these guys all went out back in front of a green screen and did a bunch of fighting with stuntmen. And you see it in trailers. You see Bedlam kicking ass. They all stayed an extra half day to do that. It was awesome.”
>
> “When they came to set we shot additional material that we knew we were just going to put in trailers that would never be in the movie,” says David Leitch. “It was all about playing a prank like only Deadpool would do. Ryan is reaching out from the screen and tickling you.”
>
> <sub>[SlashFilm, Here’s How ‘Deadpool 2’ Pulled Off That Big X-Force Moment](https://www.slashfilm.com/x-force-in-deadpool-2/)</sub>

Comment: Ryan Reynolds has said that Deadpool 3 (If it happens) will be an X Force film, so not this was not a marketing gimmick, this was an origin movie of the creation of X Force (Domino, Cable and Deadpool)

Comment: @RichardC Do you have a source for that?

Comment: https://movieweb.com/deadpool-3-not-happening-x-force-movie-next-ryan-reynolds/ .  http://collider.com/deadpool-3-ryan-reynolds-x-force-movie/ .  https://www.cinemablend.com/news/2424182/josh-brolin-talks-about-working-with-x-force-director-drew-goddard

Comment: Playing with the medium to the nth degree like this perfectly captures the essence of Deadpool. I'd say that even though the X-Force scenes in the trailers never appeared in the movie, by pranking the audience, the trailers were still completely faithful to the spirit of the film they were advertising!

Answer (score 0):

An X Force Movie has now been confirmed, Ryan Reynolds confirmed it throughout the *Deadpool 2* press interviews and talked multiple times about the fact that there would be no Deadpool 3 but instead moving forward Deadpool would appear in an X Force movie. Josh Brolin has talked about working on the X Force movie and he and Zazie Beetz have been confirmed as having signed up for the X Force movie.

A few links below but if you Google X Force, Deadpool 3, Cable or Domino there is loads of confirmed (not rumoured) information online about the future of the Deadpool Franchise.

- [Movie Web, Deadpool 3 Is Unlikely, X-Force Movie Probably Next Says Reynolds](https://movieweb.com/deadpool-3-not-happening-x-force-movie-next-ryan-reynolds/)
- [Collider, Ryan Reynolds Doesn’t Think There Will Be a ‘Deadpool 3’; Predicts ‘X-Force’ Is the Future](http://collider.com/deadpool-3-ryan-reynolds-x-force-movie/)
- [Cinema Blend, Josh Brolin Talks About Working With X-Force Director Drew Goddard](https://www.cinemablend.com/news/2424182/josh-brolin-talks-about-working-with-x-force-director-drew-goddard)
- [Screen Rant, Deadpool 2: Zazie Beetz Will Reprise Domino for X-Force](https://screenrant.com/deadpool-2-zazie-beetz-domino-x-force/)
- [Collider, Exclusive: Ryan Reynolds Gives an ‘X-Force’ Update and Talks about the Film’s Rating](http://collider.com/x-force-movie-update-ryan-reynolds/)

Comment: Linking away from the site isn't recommended. Your answer becomes redundant when the links die, where as information here is relevant as long as this site is alive. It also doesn't state there certainly won't be a Deadpool 3, just that it's unlikely.